# MySQL: get COUNT for records on a certain date and overall

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which contains entries from certain dates as such:

```
id |  word  | date
1  |  word1 | 2014-03-27 (today)
2  |  word2 | 2014-03-27 (today)
3  |  word1 | 2012-01-21
3  |  word1 | 2011-04-14
```

In the table above `word1` appears 3 times overall, but only one time today. What I would want is to create a query that shows me both today's count and in general for each of the words. The only way that I can think of is by using another `SELECT` inside the query, but that's slow and complicates things.

Is there another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that without subquery:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(word) AS all_count, 
  COUNT(IF(`date`=CURDATE(), word, NULL)) AS today_count 
FROM 
  t 
WHERE 
  word='word1'
```

Comment: Follow-up question: any idea on how to order by `today_count` in your example? I get `Reference 'today_count' not supported (reference to group function)`, so how can I isolate the value for each separate row?

Comment: Working fine for me. What is the query? (I've added `ORDER BY today_count`)

Comment: Yeah, sorry for the lack of details. My bad. What I want to do is something like `ORDER BY (today_count / all_count)`.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is so. You have two options. Either use double `COUNT` select or use subquery. Both samples I've put [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8c293a/7)

Answer (score 1):

Another idea...

```
    SELECT general.word, general.n_general, n_today
    FROM (
           (SELECT word, count(*) n_today FROM t 
            WHERE t.date>=CURDATE() GROUP BY t.word) today
    INNER JOIN
           (SELECT word, count(*) n_general FROM t 
            GROUP BY t.word) general
    ON today.word=general.word)
```

I hope this helps.